# Django, link 2 tables in different database

Tags: python, database, django

I have 2 DB

Main DB have table for model

```
class Entry(m.Model):
  value = m.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
```

Seconadry have this

```
class Feature(m.Model):
  linked = m.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

I need get dictionary like this:
{('entry':'value','linked':'id'),}

Now i get item from second table, iterate, and make list of id's, than take from main DB, and iterate again.
Is there is an options to do this in the right way? Technics, some triks?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) which allows you to [inherit from multiple parent models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multiple-inheritance). However, I am not 100% sure about it's compatibility with multiple databases.

You would have something like

```
class Entry(m.Model):
    value = m.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

class Feature(m.Model):
    linked = m.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class EntryFeature(Entry, Feature):
    ...
```

There are also alternatives if your schemas can be modified.

Comment: Its exactly in 2 different databases on 2 differens servers.
There is no common way to do this.